# How to send a not private message on Facebook?

Tags: privacy, facebook

I'm trying to figure out *how* people are managing to send *non*-private messages to each other on Facebook. You see them as something like:

> Ian Boyd ► Kirsten Guyer: Everyone can see this message.

example:

[image: screen shot]

I want to know how to send a *not*-private message, so that I can learn how to send a *private* message.

**Note**: Sending a message is different than writing on a wall.

How do I send a *not* private message on Facebook?

Comment: Can you really rend a "private" message on facebook?

Comment: @Johan: Is that a philosophical political question; like *Can anyone really "use" a web-site?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a **wall post**.

[image]

It appears in your news feed when *friend A* posts on *friend B*'s wall, and only works if *friend B* allows wall posts and has made wall posts by others public.

Comment: And this *is* a wall post (even if you said otherwise). Have a look at the screen shot you provided, it even says "See Wall-to-Wall".

Comment: That is wall post but in comment the user suggest to send the private message which is bothering him, I think. The private messages are not like this they are different. You are right.

Comment: Given this answer, i still assume there are three kinds of "messages" a) a message i wrote on someone's public wall b)a message i sent to someone, but everyone can see, and c) a message i sent to someone that only they can see.

Comment: Well, technically there are only 1) **messages** (using your message center, or the "message" button), and 2) **wall posts**. However, users have the option to entirely hide posts made by others on their wall though, so that's why you see some as public, and some that only the users themselves can see. So therefore, yes, you could say there are three types.

Comment: Where are the privacy settings for **messages** (using your message center, or the "message" button)

Comment: There are none.